Composer conflict with our library code
I am in the process of upgrading from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10.  I ran composer update --dry-run and I received the following messages.
  Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.3.0, ..., 10.3.10].
- Root composer.json requires raystedman/library dev-master -> satisfiable by raystedman/library[dev-master].
- drupal/core-recommended[10.3.0, ..., 10.3.10] require symfony/mailer ~v6.4.7 -> satisfiable by symfony/mailer[v6.4.7, ..., v6.4.13].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/mailer v6.4.13 (conflict analysis result)

I believe this is telling me that drupal/core-recommended requires symfony/mailer and that symfony/mailer is already installed as part of raystedman/library.
Here is the problem.  raystedman/library is a set of code that does not contain any calls to the drupal API.  The code is used in many places including:

Part of our Drupal website
Command Line Interface (CLI) for our server providing website utility functions

raystedman/library sends email using symfony/mailer.  The composer.json for raystedman/library requires symfony/mailer as a result.  raystedman/library is required by the composer.json at the top of the drupal directory structure.
The composer.json of raystedman/library for symfony/mailer is (^5.4).
Perhaps I need to run composer remove symfony/mailer from raystedman/library as part of the Drupal install process?
I would rather tell composer how to handle the situation and not throw an error. Is this possible?
[raystedman_org@web01 tst]$ /usr/bin/composer prohibits -r symfony/mailer 6.4.13
drupal/recommended-project -           requires         raystedman/library (dev-master)                     
raystedman/library         9999999-dev requires         symfony/mailer (^5.4)                               
symfony/mailer             v6.4.13     conflicts        symfony/http-kernel (<5.4)                          
symfony/mailer             v6.4.13     conflicts        symfony/mime (<6.2)                                 
symfony/mailer             v6.4.13     requires         symfony/event-dispatcher (^5.4|^6.0|^7.0)           
drupal/recommended-project -           does not require symfony/event-dispatcher (but v4.4.44 is installed) 
symfony/mailer             v6.4.13     requires         symfony/mime (^6.2|^7.0)                            
drupal/recommended-project -           does not require symfony/mime (but v5.4.13 is installed)


What is the version constraint for symfony/mailer in the composer.json file for raystedman/library? Add that information to the question.

Also I encourage you to use the composer prohibits -r command: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits-why-not

Thank you @mona lisa.  I am new at sorting all of this out.  I updated the question above per your thoughts.

I tried upgrading raystedman/library to use symfony/mailer (^6.4).  It turns out this is not compatable with drupal 9. Ug!

Even if you could trick composer into ignoring the conflict, it’s not going to solve the underlying problem - you have a dependency which uses the mailer API at version 5.x, and a different dependency that uses the same API, but at version 6.x. Major version == breaking changes, so you wouldn’t expect the dependency with the older constraint to cope with the new API version, without code alterations. The only real way to solve this is create a fork/version of the raystedman library which is compatible with Symfony Mailer 6.x. I suspect that’s just the tip of the iceberg as well, once you…

…start trying to upgrade that dependency, you’ll probably find out that a bunch of other supporting Symfony packages also need to be upgraded. But you would’ve had to do that anyway to get it compatible with Drupal 10 at all, so no extra work as such

Libraries should be as liberal as possible with their dependencies. Ideally you should make your library compatible with all the major versions of mailer you want to support.

Composer is working exactly as it should - it is preventing you from installing a breaking conflict, based on compatibilities. I would open a support request for the third party library asking for support for current versions of Symfony/Mailer.
